# Optimizing sum() over(order by...) clause throwing 'resources exceeded' error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm computing a sessions table from event data from out website in BigQuery. The events table has around 12 million events (pretty small). After I add in the logic to create sessions, I want to sum all sessions and assign a global_session_id. I'm doing that using a `sum()over(order by...)` clause which is throwing a resources exceeded error. I know that the order by clause is causing all the data to be processed on a single node and that is causing the compute resources to be exceeded, but I'm not sure what changes I can make to my code to achieve the same result. Any work arounds, advice, or explanations are greatly appreciated.

```
with sessions_1 as ( /* Tie a visitor's last event and last campaign to current event. */

                       select visitor_id as session_user_id,
                              sent_at,
                              context_campaign_name,
                              event,
                              id,
                              LAG(sent_at,1) OVER (PARTITION BY visitor_id ORDER BY sent_at) as last_event,
                              LAG(context_campaign_name,1) OVER (PARTITION BY visitor_id ORDER BY sent_at) as last_event_campaign_name 
                         from tracks_2
                    ),

sessions_2 as ( /* Flag events that begin a new session. */

                   select *,
                   case 
                     when context_campaign_name != last_event_campaign_name
                       or context_campaign_name is null and last_event_campaign_name is not null
                       or context_campaign_name is not null and last_event_campaign_name is null
                       then 1
                     when unix_seconds(sent_at) 
                          - unix_seconds(last_event) >= (60 * 30)
                       or last_event is null
                       then 1 
                       else 0 
                       end as is_new_session
                   from sessions_1
                    ),

sessions_3 as ( /* Assign events sessions numbers for total sessions and total user sessions. */

                     select id as event_id,
                            sum(is_new_session) over (order by session_user_id, sent_at) as global_session_id
                            #sum(is_new_session) over (partition by session_user_id order by sent_at) as user_session_id
                      from  materialized_result_of_sessions_2_query 
                      )
select * from sessions_3
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a description of your definition of session would really help.

Comment: Sessions definition is a 30min inactivity window or when the user visits the site via a different advertisement.

Comment: Desired result is a table with all unique event api ids, a unique id for each session, and a field with nth session for a given user. Working on example data.

Comment: Why does the unique id have to be a sequential value?  Or is that not a requirement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if it is not a sequential value it will impact some configuration we've made downstream, so ideally I'd like to keep the sequential value. I know one possible solution might be to create a global_session_id by combining the user_id and session start date, but wanted to see if a sequential value was possible first.

Answer (score 1):

If might help if you defined a CTE with just the sessions, rather than at the event level.  If this works:

```
select session_user_id, sent_at,
       row_number() over (order by session_user_id, sent_at) as global_session_id
from  materialized_result_of_sessions_2_query 
where is_new_session
group by session_user_id, sent_at;
```

If that doesn't work, you can construct the global id:

You can join this back to the original event-level data and then use a `max()` window function to assign it to all events.  Something like:

```
select e.*,
       max(s.global_session_id) over (partition by e.session_user_id order by e.event_at) as global_session_id
from events e left join
     (<above query>) s
     on s.session_user_id = e.session_user_id and s.sent_at = e.event_at;
```

If not, you can do:

```
select us.*, us.user_session_id + s.offset as global_session_id
from (select session_user_id, sent_at,
             row_number() over (partition by session_user_id order by sent_at) as user_session_id
      from materialized_result_of_sessions_2_query 
      where is_new_session
     ) us join
     (select session_user_id, count(*) as cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (order by session_user_id) - count(*) as offset
      from materialized_result_of_sessions_2_query
      where is_new_session
      group by session_user_id
     ) s
     on us.session_user_id = s.session_user_id;
```

This might still fail if almost all users are unique and the sessions are short.

Comment: That would work, if I didn't need the global_session_id assigned at the event level. In my process of creating a derived sessions table, I create additional boolean fields that describe what took place in a given session (ex: purchased = true, product_added = true, etc). I can't easily create these fields without a global_session_id.

Comment: @CLStingle . . . I elaborated on how you spread this information over all events.

Comment: This solution does not work b/c when joining back to the events table it will only join to events that started a session, not events that live in the session where is_new_session = 0.

Comment: @CLStingle . . . Good point.  It needs to be a `left join` with some tweaks to the window function.  I adjusted the answer.